# Confidence interval on entropy estimation

Tags: confidence-interval, references, entropy

Over a sample (of about a hundred observations), I have estimated the "empirical" entropy of a sequence of identically independently distributed random variables which have 5 possible outcomes.

I was curious to know if there was a possibility to estimate in some way a confidence interval over this "empirical" entropy calculation (i.e. where true probabilities are replaced by their observed frequencies) ?

Best regards

Comment: I've made a few edits to clear up your question a little, but I couldn't work out what to do with the singular/plural mismatches in "a repeated i.i.d. random variables"; please edit to clarify.

Comment: You can compute a confidence interval of most things by bootstrapping. Does that help?

Comment: @ Glen_b: thank's for the edit I have modified the question hopefully in accordance with your comment.  Best regards

Comment: @ Adam Ryczkowski : I was more looking at some "asymptotic normality" kind of results, but this approach might work, I have to gie ti a try. Best regards

Comment: (When referring to someone with the `@` sign make sure that there is no space between it and the user's name. Otherwise SE ignores it and people do not get alerted about the ongoing conversation).

Comment: This question is practically the same as http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25235, which addresses a hypothesis test for entropy.