# Computing the Entropy of a walk

Tags: python, markov-process, entropy, information-theory, graph-theory

Take for example a walk such as:

```
["school", "work", "home", "kindergarten", "home", "school", ...]

# or simply
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, ...]
```

**What's the correct way of computing its entropy?**

My current approach is to just count how many times each unique step is taken, compute the step-probabilities by normalizing, and then plug that into the Shannon entropy equation. Here's a small Python example:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

def time_correlated_entropy(walk):
    counter = Counter(zip(walk[:-1], walk[1:]))
    P = np.array(counter.values(), float) / np.sum(counter.values())
    return - sum(P * np.log2(P))
```

It gives sensible results, but I have no idea whether this is the *right way*, because I have no literature to hold it up against.

Comment: "Right way" must be understood with respect to a *purpose*: what are you hoping this calculation will tell you about a "walk"?

Comment: Thanks for asking @whuber. Say, the walk belongs to a man, and I would like to measure how geospacially unpredictable this man is based on the stops he make. The chronological list of stops is his walk.

Comment: I would be concerned about the possibility that your calculations give arbitrary results. Two aspects of the walk description suggest this is a risk: (1) it does not appear to distinguish the lengths of segments, so a very short segment (of little "geospatial" consequence) would be treated as the same as a very long one and (2) it depends on the detail or resolution with which you describe the walk: as the amount of detail increases, so does the entropy of the description. Are you sure that entropy is a good measure of "unpredictability" in your application?

Comment: Valid point. What I expected to capture by treating state-transitions as states with a probability, was low entropy for the "home" -> "school" -> "home" -> "school" type people, and high entropy for the people with complex state-transition patterns.

Comment: Provided you are clear about the definition and interpretation, it's an interesting approach.  I recall answering a related question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25235 .  By taking some care to weed out unrelated questions, a [search of this site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=entropy+-maximum+-dimension+-continuous+-cross+estimate+answers%3A1) turns up a few promising answers.

Comment: This sounds very similar to what you are doing: http://www.mapequation.org . It's finding graph structure based on the compressibility of random walks.

Comment: @GregVerSteeg I'm familiar with Rosvall and Infomap but to my knowledge it minimizes the average per-step description length of an infinite random walk by labeling nodes hierarchically. Is your point that one could compute the average per-step description length of the random walk? That's not so bad actually...

Comment: Now that you mention it, that does seem like overkill. It doesn't seem like you've defined a graph (i.e., probability to transition between work->school, etc.), so maybe you just want to calculate an entropy rate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_rate. Crutchfield's group studying "computational mechanics" gives several more nuanced measures, e.g. in this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5504.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unpredictability in your problem is very much related to the **entropy rate** generated by the state transitions. I suggest you have a look at the topic "computational mechanics", which addresses information-theoretic questions in stochastic processes (see e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0102181)

Think of it in the following way: a random sequence of length $L$ has entropy $H(L)$, thus the entropy rate is $h=\lim_{L\rightarrow \infty} H(L)/L$. In this case, your walker generates $h$ bits of information per step.

If you want to be a bit more fine-grained, compute also the excess entropy, which is $\lim_{L\rightarrow \infty} H(L)-h L$ which captures the amount of information you need to acquire in order to synchronize with the process.

Your example of a predictable walker gives $h=0$ and $E=1$, because as soon as you have one bit (home or work) you are fully synchronized with him, and he becomes fully predictable.

Sorry that I don't write the code. I'm still learning...